# Cannot index data using java code when started solr cloud using docker-compose

Tags: java, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, solrj, solrcloud

When hitting the solr-cloud(exposed ports are 8983) from java code using zookeeperURI(exposed port 2181) which are started using docker-compose and error is thrown saying that 
"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: No live SolrServers available to handle this request:[http://172.21.0.4:8983/solr/test]".

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: you should post your docker-compose file

Answer (score 1):

Using the parameter `-u your-hostname` when starting Solr finally worked for me. By doing that, I have zookeeper return `your-hostname` instead of the IP. You can then add:

```
127.0.0.1 your-hostname
```

to your `/etc/hosts` and that should do the magic. As I say, it worked for me.

My `docker-compose.xml` is as easy as:

```
version: '2'

services:

  ...

  oesp-zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:1
    container_name: my-zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181

  oesp-solr:
    image: solr:1
    container_name: my-solr
    depends_on:
      - my-zookeeper
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
```

Then I start Solr with:

```
solr -f -z my-zookeeper:2181 -h solr.docker
```

Answer (score 0):

The ip address returned to SolrJ (`172.21.0.4`) is the Ip of the SolrCloud container which is not reachable externally.

To solve to this problem I suggest to specify a hostname for the Solr instance instead of default ip address. Which means that you have to define the `SOLR_HOST: solr-cloud` environment variable in your `docker-compose.yml` .

Have a look at this https://github.com/freedev/solrcloud-zookeeper-docker

In particular the file `solrcloud/docker-compose.yml` is configured as I have described in former lines of my answer.

Comment: I've tried this approach, but didn't work. I get an exception when trying to search from my Java code:

`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find a healthy node to handle the request.`

If I don't set the `SOLR_HOST` variable, the problem I have the same as the original question. Any idea?

1. My Java app asks Zookeper for a Solr code.
2. Zookeeper returns Solr Docker container IP
3. My Java app tries to access this IP, failing (as Docker won't allow it)

Comment: As said, you should post your docker-compose file. The other way is use an [SolrJ HTTP Client](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient.html) which does not need any zookeeper connection.

Comment: Using the Solr param `-u` worked for me (probably the same as you suggested by using `SOLR_HOST`?). Anyway, I've added the details in an answer.